# Best method to tackle both csrf and authentication problem in NodeJS server

Tags: android, node.js, web, jwt, csrf

I am new to web server development. I am developing a NodeJS web server, which serves both web (AngularJS/ReactJS) and native mobile application (Android).
There is a user-specific feature in my project.

I am confused and spent a few hours searching for security issues related to csrf and authentication.

My question is

1) which method should I use to tackles both **csrf and authentication** issue in both **Web and Mobile application**? - Is it **JWT (JSON web token)** or **CSURF** middle-ware in express JS.

please explain in detail.

If there is any other method please mention.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Passport + Passport strategy + helmet or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

JWT should work for authentication as well as csrf protection. You can use jwt to store the csrf token. Store the JWT in a secure http-only cookie and also store the csrf token in your session storage. Then verify that the token in jwt matches the csrf token sent with the request. Additionally you can use JWT for doing authorisation at later stages.

You can also have a look at jwt-csrf which uses jwt for anti-csrf protection. The default method it uses for anti-csrf token is double submit but it also supports other methods.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-csrf